# Creating a visual GUI

Tags: c#, user-interface

I would like to know how to create an custom user interface for a program I am making.
What I want to add besides the default buttons and text boxes is an raster image frame inside of the application and some raster image buttons that change their animation/image.
And also learn how to draw additional items on the screen (buttons, input boxes) after pressing the desired selector button (for input types).

All in all - I would appreciate it if some one pointed me to a tutorial for this or code examples I can learn from.

Comment: you need a tutorial for it, or a program that will help you do it?

Comment: This will be closed a s too broad, probably. It's also incomplete: do you want to use HTML, WinForms, WPF? Have you studied any of those? Phone or desktop?

Comment: Windows form application. It will connect to an local SQL database.

Comment: Enter doesn't make new line...
I just need an code example that will show me how to import my properly made images for the job of creating an GUI.

Comment: did you try google? "c# sql example" or something like that? i suppose you mean sql-server

Comment: I dont need SQL help, I need GUI help.

Comment: To display an Image use the PictureBox. To draw stuff onto some Control use its Paint event and trigger it by calling someControl.Invalidate()

Comment: Google for "winforms skins"...

Comment: Add all that extra info to the question, add relevant tags and try to make it more concrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have http://www.wpftutorial.net/ to learn how to create WPF interfaces (Windows Presentation Foundation) for Windows / Phone.

Comment: Thank you. (additional characters so this thing will post)